# Jquery Show Page Loading on title bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

With JQuery how can I show the Loading on title bar?

You can see the **loading** near to **New Tab**, in the title bar. Similar way I want to show using JQuery.

Is there any way?

[image]

Comment: I have an Ajax call.  Right now I am setting the cursor loading while getting data. But I was wondering if there is any way to show like this. Not a big deal anyway. Couldn't find in google. So asked here

Comment: there is a trick use iframe and load content in it.

Comment: use a iframe and call url in iframe which you want to call in ajax. it is trick only. because browser show loader only when a request is generated by url.

Comment: Did you try `$("title").text("Loading")` and `$("title").text("Original Title")`?

Comment: Thats just a text. That I can Set. I am changing the title when the page loads. I wanted some animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is browser specific loader, It is not possible to change this loader.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. What about changing the favicon? may b I can set a loading gif while page loads?

Comment: no favicon come after page loaded, u still see the loader wheel first.

Comment: I am calling using Ajax. That time is it Ok to set while calling and revert back after loading?